# progressbar not updating binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a progress bar that updates when a property value changes
I have followed other questions but i don't know what is wrong with it.

This is XAML code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-8,1">
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progreso, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" Margin="105,95,207,350"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" Margin="218,232,333,217"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

it is basically a progress bar with the binding and a button with a listener that increases Progreso by 10
this is the C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string sProp)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sProp));
        }
    }

    float progreso = 10;
    public float Progreso
    {
        get
        {
            return progreso;
        }
        set
        {
            progreso = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Progreso");
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Progreso = this.Progreso + 10;
    }

}
```

I tried to keep it simple but I couldn't get it to work, any help with this would be appreciated.

edit: I've also tried  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and that didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you missed the declaration of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  //....
}
```

**NOTE**: Using `RelativeSource` works OK, I tested this. Using `DataContext` is just an implicit way to set the `Source` although it's a convenient and a recommended way.

### UPDATE

About using `DataContext`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progreso}" Margin="105,95,207,350"/>
```

Comment: thank you, got it working, but by using `DataContext` you mean using  `ElementName=TheWindow`, `DataContext=This` in code, or is there another way? what would be the best way? or are all equally okay?

Comment: @BoteRock when using `DataContext`, you just need to set the `Path` property (which is `Progreso` in your code). As I said, using `DataContext` is more convenient and a recommended way, especially when you use `MVVM`.

Comment: @BoteRock see my update for detail, it's much shorter. But it doesn't always replace `RelativeSource`, the important thing is we should know when use this one rather than that one.

Comment: thought there was a way to put `DataContext` in xaml, like saying that the `DataContext` of every content of the window to be the window itself. Thank you for your info about DataContexts

Answer (score 2):

`AncestorType`  does not seem to work property. So you have two options:

1. Set Window `Name` and find `DataContext` by `ElementName`
2. Set `DataContext` to be `this` in code behind and remove RelativeSource part

Comment: The `Binding` of the OP explicitly sets its `RelativeSource`, using `DataContext` means using an implicit source.